# PyCharm настройки

Tags: python, pycharm

1. Как убрать серую полосу(та, которая правее центра)?
   [image: серая полоса]
2. Как включить отображение пробелов?
3. Как отключить автодополнение при нажатии  <kbd>пробела</kbd> либо <kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: Через `settings` (Ctrl-Alt-S) пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Надо зайти в настройки: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> или в меню File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> "Unbox Right Margin".
2. Аналогично: поставьте галочку "Show whitespaces".
3. Тоже в настройках: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys, а там  "Insert Self..."

Comment: спасибо, только эти (1,2) настройки находятся в File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance

Comment: @Spherastree В разных версиях перекладывают в новые места. Это чтобы нам удобнее было :-)